# Replacing Nimh battery to Li-ion in hybrid cars

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, electrical, nimh, lithium-ion

is it a good idea to replace a Nimh battery in hybrid car (like prius model 2012) to Li-ion battery without any problems.

Comment: Welcome. Should not be a problem as Toyota mechanics would do this. The Li-Po battery is very heavy and expensive. This is not a hobby project.

Comment: Thank you, but can I replace it without any problems like battery burn or high temperature.